# I am really confused about the use of ones in following sentences

Tags: grammar

1. ones personal traits can be highly influenced by its surroundings and education.
2. an individual surroundings plays a vital role in shaping ones personality
3. numerous things can be done to mould ones character

Comment: You mean _one's_?

Comment: Can you clarify your question please.  "I'm confused" is not a question. What is confusing? Are you confused by the difference between the numeral "one (two, three)" and the third person pronoun "one", (meaning "a person")

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the phrase *ones* in all the above cases requires an apostrophe. That is, the correct form is *one's*.

As you may know, apostrophe + s is used to create a [possessive form](http://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/apostrophe/possessives). When we use "'s" with the word "one" rather than a specific name such as "John's", we mean to refer to a **general person** rather than any specific individual. As such, *one's* can typically be replaced by *an individua's* in the above applications. Example:

One's personal traits can be highly influenced by its surroundings and education. =>
An individual's personal traits can be highly influenced by its surroundings and education.

Also, check [here](https://brians.wsu.edu/2016/05/19/ones-ones/).